# Get number of minutes called and data usage in app

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, mobile

Is it possible to get the number of minutes called and the data usage within an app, for instance native Android / iPhone or hybrid such as PhoneGap?

Any hints / links in the right direction would be very appreciated.